# В чем отличие & от && на примере конструктора копирования и конструктора переноса?

Tags: c++, c++11, конструктор, семантика

Допустим, у нас есть класс с обычным конструктором:

```
   class SomeClass { 
    int size; 
    int *element; 
   public: 
    SomeClass(int i) { //обычный конструктор
     size = i; 
     element = new int[size]; 
     } 
    };
```

И предположим, что я добавил туда конструктор копирования и конструктор перемещения (переноса):

```
SomeClass( SomeClass &&other ) { //конструктор перемещения
 size = other.size; 
 element = other.element; 
 other.size = 0; 
 other.element = nullptr; 
} 

SomeClass( SomeClass &other ) { //конструктор копирования
 size = other.size; 
 element = other.element; 
 other.size = 0; 
 other.element = nullptr; 
} 

int main()  {
 SomeClass a1(5);
 SomeClass a2(a1); //вызов конструктора копирования
 SomeClass a3 = move(a1); //вызов конструктора переноса
}
```

Здесь один нюанс: конструктор копирования не будет копировать, он тоже будет выполнять перенос.

В чем тогда отличие? Если фактически происходит одно и тоже. Code::Blocks выдает разницу в секунду. Думаю, тогда вопрос встает между использованием `&` и `&&`.

Я знаю, что второе - это ссылка на r-value, и что она позволяет обратиться к ресурсам объекта. Но ведь в обоих случая создается новый объект. В чем тогда профит?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Конструктор перемещения это чисто конвенциональная конструкция(так же как и конструктор копирования, собственно), поэтому никто не мешает делать в любом конструкторе всё, что заблагорассудится. Другое дело, что программист, использующий Ваш класс, будет ожидать перемещения от конструктора перемещения и никак не будет ожидать такого подвоха от конструктора копирования.

В том числе и поэтому, конструктор копирования всегда объявляется с константным аргументом, а не как у Вас. Ещё раз, конструкторы имеют свои названия исходя из того, что они делают *по умолчанию*(т.е. тогда, когда их генерирует компилятор). Соответственно, программист тоже должен делать так, как делается по умолчанию, а не придумывать реализацию, которая больше похожа на саботаж, чем на что-либо другое.

Исходя из всего вышесказанного: Ваш вопрос не имеет смысла.

---

Отличным примером перемещающего конструктора копирования является `std::auto_ptr`. Все мы знаем его судьбу.

Answer (score 3):

Существует несколько категорий выражений, наболее известные - это "rvalue" и "lvalue".

Переменная с типом `T&&` может принимать только r-value выражение,
переменная с типом `T&` может принимать только не константные l-value выражения.
Совершенно не важно, что это за переменная - агрумент конструктора или нет.

Соответственно разница между `SomeClass( SomeClass &&other )` и `SomeClass( SomeClass &other )` - только в том, что первый будет вызываться только для r-value выражений, а второй - только для неконстантных l-value выражений.
При этом ни один из них не может принимать `const SomeClass &`.

Что именно делают конструкторы - никому не важно, то что у них одинаковый код - это тоже не важно. Единственное отличие - это категории выражений, которые они могут принимать.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш конструктор копирования изменяет состояние объекта, с которого делается копия. Соответственно, такую операцию уже нельзя в полной мере назвать копированием.

Правильная сигнатура конструктора копирования такая:

```
SomeClass( const SomeClass &other )
```

Comment: Любой нешаблонный конструктор, принимающий ссылку `&` на класс, является копирующим конструктором этого класса. Независимо от наличия или отсутствия `const` и/или `volatile`.

Answer (score 0):

> В чем тогда профит?

Rvalue ссылки позволяют программистам избегать логически ненужного копирования и обеспечивать возможность идеальной передачи (perfect forwarding). Прежде всего они предназначены для использования в высоко производительных проектах и библиотеках.